# Keeping branch syncronized with git origin/master

Tags: git

As seen below, I cloned a repository.  You don't see this below, but I then made some changes to my local files a couple of times and pushed the changes to the repository.  Then, as shown below, and pulled the changes in.

But when I use `git status`, it says I am two commits ahead of the original/master.  Why is this?  As shown below, I clearly did not make any changes.  Using `git log` shows nothing different than the local files I pushed to the repository.

```
  784  git clone git@example.com:root/example.git
  785  ls -l
  786  cd example
  787  ls -l
  788  cd html
  789  ls -l
  790  pwd
  791  ls -l
  792  pwd
  793  cd ..
  794  git pull origin master
  795  pwd
  796  git pull origin master
  797  git status
  798  history
-sh-4.1$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
-sh-4.1$

-sh-4.1$ git remote -v
origin  git@example.com:root/example.git (fetch)
origin  git@example.com:root/example.git (push)
-sh-4.1$
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you committed or pushed your changes to the remote repo, it looks like you just committed to local and didn't push to origin.

Comment: Are you maybe misunderstanding the difference between push and pull?  If you do a git push of a local commit you don't need to do a git pull afterward.

Comment: @lukevp  I didn't show the pushed changes.  These were done on another machine.  What I am showing is that I cloned a repository, never edited any files on the shown machine, and pulled to update it.  Why would it be ahead of the master?

Comment: You are cloning `example.git`, but you never `cd` into the created `example` directory. What does `git remote -v` show?

Comment: @DonBottstein  Sorry, I manually changed it from biddersite to example, and did not change that line.  Also, see the extra I added to the end of the post regarding `git remote -v`.  Thank you

Comment: No worries. You might try `git reset --soft head~2`, then `git status` to see what the changes were. The reset will 'undo' the last two commits locally, but leave the working copies of your files unchanged.

Comment: A `git diff origin/master` is completly sufficient to see the changes. No need to use `git reset`.

Comment: `git log HEAD --not origin/master` will show you those commits that you haven't yet pushed.